# Converting an NSObject like AFXAuthToken into NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, afnetworking, keychain

I have an AFXAuthToken object that I want to store in the keychain via a library called [UICKeychainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore), but it needs a data object to be passed. If I have an AFXAuthToken object, how do I make it an NSData object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to post sample code here, but I decided to just submit a pull request to the project.  [This pull request](https://github.com/romaonthego/AFXAuthClient/pull/4) adds NSCoding support to AFXAuthToken.

Answer (score 1):

Because AFXAuthToken doesn't conform to `NSCoding`, it would be very hard to reliably encode the data it represents.  However, it is a very good candidate for serialization.  You can fork the project and implement keyed coding in the class, then it becomes a matter of using NSKeyedArchiver to get the data instance you need.

Comment: Here's some great sample code for people who haven't used NSKeyedArchiver: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/